# Plural of "staff" (stick) — "staffs" or "staves"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Which would be the correct use in the following sentence.

> I'm a Shepard and I have many staffs/staves.

Comment: [Staff](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/staff#staff__9) — see the "more examples" section.

Comment: If it's a plural of the item "a staff" (stick) it would be staves.

Answer (score 15):

For staff in the sense of "a body of employees", the plural is always staff; otherwise, both staffs and staves are acceptable, except in compounds, such as flagstaffs. Staves is rare in North America except in the sense of "magic rod", or the musical notation tool; stave of a barrel or cask is a back-formation from staves, which is its plural.

Comment: Now _this_ develops OP's question, which I'm totally in favour of.

Comment: However, [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/58698-staff-staffs.html) is an opinion I agree with: '... the term "staff", when referring to a group of people working together, is a singular count noun with plural reference, like "team". So it is correct to speak of the "staffs" of various companies, just as it's correct to speak of various teams in a league.'

Answer (score 2):

When referring to a staff in the sense of the following definitions (as you seem to mean, given your example regarding shepherds), both the plural forms *staffs* and *staves* are permitted. [[source]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/staff?s=t)

> . . .
>
> 6) a stick, pole, or rod for aid in walking or climbing, for use as a weapon, etc.
>
> 7) a rod or wand serving as a symbol of office or authority, as a crozier, baton, truncheon, or mace.
>
> 8) a pole on which a flag is hung or displayed.
>
> . . .
>
> 11) *Archaic*. the shaft of a spear, lance, etc.

Comment: Exactly. Readily answerable by looking in a single source. General reference.

Comment: I believe staffs is actually american English. In the UK staff(as a plural) or staves would be more common. The only time I've heard the word staffs used is as a common abbreviation of the county of Staffordshire so this could get very confusing.